# How do I make a "+mention" command in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do I create a discord command for my bot that will mention someone?

For ex:

Sample input: `+mention Gamer222`

Sample output: `@Gamer222#6478`

I have tried multiple things like:

```
if(command === "mention") {
   const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
   message.channel.send(`${sayMessage}`);
}
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: Next time please post the answer on a new answer, and not edited into the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer previously posted on the question:

```
if (command === "mention") {
  const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
  message.channel.send(client.users.find('username', sayMessage).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this :

```js
if (command == "mention") {
   const sayMessage = message.mentions.users.first()
   if(!sayMessage) return message.channel.send("Please mention a user.")
   message.channel.send(`${sayMessage}`)
}
```